# How we can download files/folder from storage.googleapis.com by using php

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

How we can download files/folder from storage.googleapis.com by using php.
i try to download files/folder from http://storage.googleapis.com
is it possible with php?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can do this several different ways. The easiest way is probably to use the [gcloud-php project](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-php/#/). Example:

```
use Google\Cloud\ServiceBuilder;

$gcloud = new ServiceBuilder([
    'keyFilePath' => '/path/to/key/file.json',
    'projectId' => 'myProject'
]);

$storage = $gcloud->storage();
$bucket = $storage->bucket('myBucket');
$object = $bucket->object('myObject.txt');
$object->downloadToFile('someLocalFile.txt');
```

Other options include the [Google API PHP client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/) or manually using PHP's HTTP libraries to download the object.

Comment: This is my online storage url https://storage.googleapis.com/BucketName/            This bucket contain several folders like js,Css,Font..etc.. i want to download this folders with all files..is it possible?

Comment: Sure, you can use a command line utility like `gsutil` to copy the entire bucket or folders in it to your local machine.

Comment: Can you give a demo ?

Comment: Sure. Say you want to download everything that starts with "website/" in the bucket "someBucket" to the local directory "localDirectory". Install gsutil, and run `gsutil cp -r gs:/someBucket/website localDirectory`. More details here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#how-names-are-constructed

Comment: Is it need any authentication?

Comment: How we can perform this action in php ..while clicking a button

Comment: Ah, no. If you want to do this in PHP, you'll need to actually program it. Use the list() method to get a list of objects, pick the ones that match the pattern you want, and repeatedly call download to fetch them.

Comment: use Google\Cloud\ServiceBuilder;                                                                                       what was it..?